# Passing the same data between parent and child component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular and trying to implement the following:

I had all my functionalities within the same component, but due to the fact that it was getting bigger and bigger, I devided to refactor my code and create several components.

I am operating on a lot of data, change their value and do stuffs based on that changed value.

E.g.
I have a variable which is holding the value of a data table.
Based on a user action (e.g. button click), I call another component to which I gave the value of this table and changing some of its values and pass it back to the parent component to display the changed table value again.

Lets assume I have:

```
const datasource: MatTableDataSource<MyObject>
```

I pass this datasource as an @Input to my child component.
I do some stuff and I whish to pass my modiedied data back to the parent which is responsible to show it.
I created another variable, e.g.:

```
const modifiedDatasource: MatTableDataSource<MyObject>
```

...which I give back to my parent as @Output.
and there I pass its value to the original object:

```
this.datasource = modifiedDatasource;
```

Is there any other way to do staffs like this?

I have really a lot of such variables and objects and I do not find it well fill my code with @Inputs and @Outputs and such overwrite-value methods.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parent / Child component communication angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352880/parent-child-component-communication-angular-2)

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a service and use observables  - https://www.positronx.io/angular-service-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: Thank you all! I managed to do it this way. :)