# How to send data from one component to another via observable and display the data in the secound html template in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Hello I'm trying to send an object from 1. Component to 2. Component on a click event. Currently I try this using a data service who has a get- and set-function:

**Service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service{

 private subject = new Subject<any>();

 setDataObject(obj) { 
  this.subject.next(obj) 
 }

 getDataObject(obj): Observable <any> {
  return this.subject;
 }
}
```

On the 1. Component I trigger the setDataObject(obj) on a click event.

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of tableElements;" (click)="onSelect(item)">
 ...
```

**1. Component**

```
export class ParentComponent {

 constructor(private service: Service) { }

 onClick(obj: object) {
    this.service.setDataObject(obj);
 }
}
```

On the 2. Component I'm now unsure how to subscribe correctly to the Observable and could just save the object from 1.Component to another variable. But I have read that you shouldn't use the observable  that way.

**2. Component**

```
export class ChildComponent {
  displayObservable$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.displayObservable$ = service.getDataObject().pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log('value from service' + res);
        return res;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

So how can I display the object and its properties in my HTML-Template? I already tried:

**Child Component HTML**

`<div>Value from Service = {{ displayObservable$ | async }}</div>"`

but while my console.log shows the obj it doesn't get displayed in the template.

Comment: What's the relationship between the said components? Is it a parent-child relationship? Or are the components completely independent?

Comment: Its a parent-child relationship @thisdotutkarsh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parent / Child component communication angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352880/parent-child-component-communication-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example of how you can set the observable within a basic service, then subscribe to it from another component.

After receiving the value from the observable, you can then display it within the calling component's HTML template using an async pipe observable.

`Service`

*TS*

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  subject: Subject<number> = new Subject();

  setDataObject(obj) { 
    this.subject.next(obj); 
  }
  
  getDataObject(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject; 
  }
}
```

`Client Component`

*TS*

The code below we initialize the asynchronous observable without subscribing to it and provide a method to set the value of the observable within the service with a random number.

```
export class AppComponent {
  displayObservable$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private api: Service) {

  this.displayObservable$ = api.getDataObject().pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log('value from service = ' + res);
        return res;
      })
    );
  }

  sendValue(val: any) {
    let num: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    console.log('value sent to service = ' + num);
    this.api.setDataObject(num);
  }
}
```

`HTML`

The following HTML consists of a button to dispatch a value to the service and an
`async` observable to display the response:

```
<div>Value from service = {{ displayObservable$ | async }}</div>

<p>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    id="btnSendValue"
    (click)="sendValue($event)">
    Send a value to service
  </button>
</p>
```

Comment: I think this should actually work like this but in my case it somehow doesn't. The part `{{ displayObservable$ | async }}` doesn't show anything. The difference I see between your  example and my code is that I call the sendValue() function from a second component. I updated my question with more detailed code.